# How to create single object with multiple keys and elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have one array with `key` and its `array` elements

When I am converting it from array to object then I am getting `index` 0 and 1 but here I need index should be `array1` and `array2`

```js
let input = [{
    "array1": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test 1"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Test 2"
    }]
  },
  {
    "array2": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Test 2"
      }
    ]
  }
];


function convert(arr) {
  let obj = new Object();

  arr.forEach((value, key) => {
    obj = value;
  });
  return obj;
}
console.log(convert(input))
```

so after calling this function i am getting following output

```
{
  "array2": [
     {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test 1"
     },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Test 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

but here I need output should be like this

```
{
  "array1": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Test 2"
    }
  ],
  "array2": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Test 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I use the define the array inside the convert function and push it then again i am getting  the `index` 0 and 1.

How can i get expected result here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`) is the key:

```js
let input = [{
    "array1": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test 1"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Test 2"
    }]
  },
  {
    "array2": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Test 2"
      }
    ]
  }
];


function convert(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, ...curr }), {});
}
console.log(convert(input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

You could also combine it with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) on the array itself:

```js
let input = [{
    "array1": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test 1"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Test 2"
    }]
  },
  {
    "array2": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Test 2"
      }
    ]
  }
];


function convert(arr) {
  return Object.assign(...arr);
}
console.log(convert(input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 2):

For getting a single object with the wanted keys, you could assign all items to a single object with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
let input = [{ array1: [{ id: 1, name: "Test 1" }, { id: 2, name: "Test 2" }] }, { array2: [{ id: 1, name: "Test 1" }, { id: 2, name: "Test 2" }] }],
    object = Object.assign(...input);

console.log(object)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

---

Your code does not work because you take the latest assignment as a result

```
function convert(arr) {
    let obj = new Object();       // initialization

    arr.forEach((value, key) => {
        obj = value;              // assignment
    });
    return obj;                   // returns last assignment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code

```
function convert(arr) {
   let obj = new Object();
   arr.forEach((value, key) => {
     obj[key] = value;
   });
   return obj;
}
```

You were doing `obj = value;` on each iteration in the forEach which would mean you reassign obj to be the new value every time.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use your key parameter of foreach function in your object. I am attaching the code below you can look.

```js
let input = [{
    "array1": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test 1"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Test 2"
    }]
  },
  {
    "array2": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Test 2"
      }
    ]
  }
];


function convert(arr) {
  let obj = new Object();

  arr.forEach((value, key) => {
    obj[key] = value;
  });
  return obj;
}
console.log(convert(input))
```

Comment: Some IDEs will object to your new Object, instead use `let obj = {};`

Comment: I believe it is identical to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55530612/295783